Restrict IP access to the Django admin deployed on Render app
Good day, community. I am developing a Django application for an online store, where the seller will publish their products through the admin panel, and customers will see the products through views and templates. While I was developing locally, there was no problem accessing the admin panel since I was running it from my PC. However, now that I have deployed the application on Render app, I've just realized that I can access the admin panel by appending 'admin/' to the URL. How can I restrict access to the admin panel to certain IPs, like a firewall, meaning only my IP can access the admin panel?
Please help me
I have the starter plan

The administrator page can only be accessed when is_staff is True.
Didn't you grant administrator privileges to all users?

By "restrict access to the admin panel" you mean "do not let any one see the page at all". What some think you mean is "do not allow login".

can you setup your web server like here https://serverfault.com/questions/1023932/how-to-block-x-forwarded-for-ip-in-nginx ?

thanks for your comments guys, i did not be notify. I mean restrict access to admin panel, in, for example, only my laptop, through its IP can have access to admin panel. no other device (assuming that my laptop always will be at my home, so, the IP never changes). Because, currently, when, through any device, even in a public pc, I can access to admin panel, and I don't want that, obviusly, security reasons.
sorry, I am a beginner in this

General users cannot access the administrator panel.
They can only see the login page and the rest of the pages are inaccessible. What are you talking about???

I work at Render.
We don't a way to configure rules based on the URI path, so what others have recommended in the comments to your question would be the correct way to go: allow your users to be flagged as admins. You could also add custom rules within your code that looks at the incoming IP address to see if it matches your own rules (eg, in case your IP address changes).
